# RCurl::getURL exceeds maximum number of clients

Tags: r, curl, ftp, rcurl

I am trying to list files hosted on the FTP servers of the MODIS Global Evapotranspiration Project (MOD16) recurrently.

```
## required package
library(RCurl)

## ftp server
ch_ftp <- "ftp://ftp.ntsg.umt.edu/pub/MODIS/NTSG_Products/MOD16/MOD16A2.105_MERRAGMAO/"

## list and reformat available subfolders
ch_fls <- getURL(ch_ftp, verbose = TRUE, dirlistonly = TRUE)

ls_fls <- strsplit(ch_fls, "\n")
ch_fls <- unlist(ls_fls)

## list files in current folder
for (i in ch_fls) {

  ch_hdf <- paste0(ch_ftp, i)
  getURL(ch_hdf, verbose = TRUE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
}
```

After some iterations, `RCurl::getURL` throws the following error message.

```
< 530 Sorry, the maximum number of clients (5) from your host are already connected.
* Access denied: 530
* Closing connection 16
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Access denied: 530
```

Obviously, `RCurl::getURL` opens connections to the FTP server during each iteration without closing them fast enough. A few minutes later, the server is accessible again, but the same error message will be thrown when re-initializing the script and waiting for the first few iterations. Is there a way to manually close the connections established by `RCurl::getURL` immediately after having retrieved a list of files?

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with the same issue.

Using `Sys.sleep(2)` fixed it for me.

```
## list files in current folder
for (i in ch_fls) {

  ch_hdf <- paste0(ch_ftp, i)
  getURL(ch_hdf, verbose = TRUE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

Comment: True, the connections are closed automatically after a certain amount of time which suggests to use `Sys.sleep`. Still, I'm wondering if there is a (CURL) possibility to close the connections opened during `getURL` manually to speed things up a little bit.

Comment: I agree, I'm still looking for a more elegant solution in line with closing connections.